# How to detect widget type in Symfony Twig rendering?

Tags: symfony, twig

For rendering form rows, I need to detect what type of widget is being rendered. For example for checkboxes I want the label before the input, so I did this:

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="row">
        {% if form.vars.block_prefixes[1] == "checkbox" %}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            {{ form_label(form) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {% else %}
            <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                {{ form_label(form) }}
            </div>
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

I used **form.vars.block_prefixes[1]** to determine the widget it's about to render. Is that right? Or is there a better method? I can't seem to find it in the docs.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a reliable way to do this, which is really unfortunate. It's not reliable to refer to the index of the variable in `form.vars.block_prefixes` as it's not consistent across versions of Symfony.

Comment: That what I thought, @Daria has provided the right information below. Thanks to both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you see [symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes), you can find:

> the block name is a combination of the field type and which part of the field is being rendered (e.g. widget, label, errors, row)

So, to customize checkbox form type rendering, you can define checkbox_widget block and checkbox_row for widgets order:

```
{% block checkbox_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
        <label {% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>
            {{ label }}
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />  
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}

{% block checkbox_row %}
{% spaceless %}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_row %}
```

Comment: Perfect, the checkbox_row was what I needed, don't know how I missed that from the doc. Thanks @Daria

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank  you. But for any Symfony devs reading this, a `type` variable should contain this information.

Comment: However, what if we wanted to add a special class to the form, based on the "type" of input, e.g. this works but is not a valid method: `{% block widget_attributes %}
    {% set formControlCss = ' inputType-' ~ form.vars.block_prefixes.1 %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('')}) %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock widget_attributes %}`. In this situation, extending the blocks wouldn't work, unless you made a block for EVERY SINGLE type...

Comment: @ChadwickMeyer check my answer. There is a way of adding any global data you need for all form types.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any data you need in the templates and symfony doesn't provide it by default you can always create a [form type extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html)

A form type extension is a mechanism that let's you extend many form types in a single place. You can extend all form types provided you define the right extended type (`FormType::class` if you want to extend all forms).

This extension provides both the `block_type` for the current instance and the class name for all form types. This let's you use these variables in any generic template (such as `widget_attributes`).

I only tested it on `symfony 3.4`

```
<?php
namespace YourBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;

class FormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $type = $form->getConfig()->getType();
        $inner_type = $type->getInnerType();

        $view->vars = array_replace($view->vars, array(
            'block_prefix' => $type->getBlockPrefix(),
            'type_name' => get_class($inner_type)
        ));
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FormType::class;
    }
}
```